# Truncation, iid's and convergence of expectation

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X_i$'s iid and we set $Y_k= X_k {1} _{\{ |X_k|\leq k\}}$.
At the proof of 1.8.6 in [this](https://math.la.asu.edu/~jtaylor/teaching/Spring2011/APM504/lectures/lecture8/lecture8.pdf) it says that $E[Y_k]$ goes to $\mu=E[X_1]$ as 
$k\rightarrow \infty$ and I am trying to figure out how do we get this. Could you help me with that?

Initially, I thought that it would be derived from the convergence of random variables and that's why I asked the following question:

Is it true that $Y_k\rightarrow X_1$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$ pointwise?

Also if we had $Z_k=a_k X_k {1} _{\{ |X_k|\leq k\}}$ with $a_k$ bounded sequence of constants, can we derive a pointwise limit?

Thanks

Comment: Why would it converge pointwise at all? Typically an iid sequence is highly oscillatory in time. You do have convergence in distribution but you should expect nothing else.

Comment: Is this from a textbook or did you just make it up?

Comment: At the proof of 1.8.6 in this https://math.la.asu.edu/~jtaylor/teaching/Spring2011/APM504/lectures/lecture8/lecture8.pdf it says that $E[Y_k]$ got to $\mu=E[X_1]$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$ and I am trying to figure out how do we get this.

Comment: @MathewJames convergence of the means does not necessarily follow from convergence of the RVs. Consider editing your question to ask exactly which object you care about: the RV or their expectations.

Comment: Additionally, use @ followed by the user's name when replying in comments. This is so that they get notified and are more likely to see the comment/respond.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 thanks for your directions. I thought that it would come from convergence of RVs, since it mentioned dominated convergence. I changed my initial question

Comment: @MathewJames oh sorry for the misdirection, i hadnt time to see the link yet; in that case yes. They use 3 lemmas and a theorem to get convergence of the RV and then they appeal to DCT for the convergence of means. You should carefully take a look at the lemmas and theorems they reference prior to the step where they apply DCT.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 I have seen the lemmas, but I don't think that they are connected with the specific part of the proof I am talking about. I mean can understand the whole proof except for this specific argument about the convergence of expectations, which I think is a separate argument with no connection with the above proof.

Answer (score 0):

$Y_k$ and $X_1$ are independent for $k \neq 1$; there is no relationship to be had between them.

More precisely, if the distribution of the $X_i$'s is anything other than a constant distribution, then
$$ \mathbb{P}\left( X_1 = \lim_{k \to \infty} Y_k \right) = 0 $$
Consequently, I can't imagine any ad-hoc sense in which one could say it is true either.

---

Based on your comments, it sounds like the idea you're *actually* looking for is that the variables converge, but the *distributions* of the variables converge.

That is, the *distribution* of $Y_k$  converges (as $k \to \infty$) to the *distribution* of $X_1$.

(and furthermore, it is not the actual *distributions* you ask to converge, but their expectations; without thinking about all of the details, I'm not sure whether to think that expectation is continuous; i.e. whether the limit of expectations should be the expectation of the limit)

Comment: And could you help me to see how do we take the convergence in distribution?