# If $X_i$'s iid and $Y_k= X_k {1} _{\{ |X_k|\leq k\}}$, then $E[Y_k]\rightarrow E[X_1]$

Tags: probability

I want to show that if $X_i$'s iid and $Y_k= X_k {1} _{\{ |X_k|\leq k\}}$, then $E[Y_k]\rightarrow E[X_1]$.

My notes say that this holds by dominated convergence theorem but I can't see how to take this result. My problem is that the truncation takes the bound $k$ and not something independent of $k$ -in the latter case I can show the result with DCT.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Since $X_k$ and $X_1$ follow the same distribution, $$E(Y_k)=E(X_1\mathbf 1_{|X_1|\leqslant k})$$ Now, $X_1\mathbf 1_{|X_1|\leqslant k}\to X_1$ almost surely, when $k\to\infty$, hence...

Comment: Hmmm... Why [the duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2486524/)?

Comment: @Did I messed up with the previous question, I had formulated it really badly in the beginning and I confused those who replied, that's why I asked again clearly what I wanted. Sorry if that was a problem. Your answer makes sense to me, thanks a lot.